# Trying to load external website page from my ASP.NET MVC3 app into a popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cross-domain

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 website which need to display a card validation page in a popup. Card validation page is actually on external website and I cannot change it. One of the requirements is that I have to do a POST request to that external page and pass custom header in order to pre-populate card number into their text box. I tried suing javascript .ajax call, but that returns

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ...
```

because they haven't enabled cross domain access. If I use custom Action and inside that a webclient to do a post and then download a response string and then pass it back to a view it doesn't really work as I get pure html source from their page and it loses all relative references they have to scripts and css files as they now point to my site. Is there any way to do it? Ideally I want to load their page with POST request into some iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is open the popup and load the initial content for the popup from your website. This content contains a hidden form with all data that needs to be `POST`-ed to the card validation service. After the page is loaded (i.e. document ready) you use javascript to automatically submit the hidden form. In case javascript is not available (`<noscript>...</noscript>`) you could show a simple submit button that the user needs to click to submit the hidden form.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code. How can I also put headers into post request of submitted form?

Comment: You mean custom HTTP headers? Is that service really designed to be called from a browser? If it's dependent on custom HTTP headers it sounds more like a webservice. Sounds like you are trying to use something for what it wasn't designed for. What service are we talking about? Can you provide a link to the specifications of that card validation service?

Comment: It turns out it was impossible to do that. I got them to move parameter from POST header to post parameters and now I can use a hidden form method.